# php - cannot load image from database

Tags: php

I'm trying to design a page in php which shows images from database. or I would say only the location of images are in database.

But, when it shows up the images.. But it does print the image path.. That means it is getting the image path without any issue.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "foodies");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to mysql";
    mysqli_connect_error();
}
   $sql = "select img, name from products";
   $result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $img = $row["img"];
        $name = $row["name"];
        //$srcc = "C:\wamp\www\foodies\images";
        //$quality=100;
        //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
        echo "<img src='".$row['img']."' width=200 height=200/>";

        ?>
```

Comment: So, the paths are wrong? Can you give an example of a path stored in your DB?

Comment: Your code may contain syntax errors. 
Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Plus, there's a probable missing backslash missing in your commented `$srcc = "C:\wamp\www\foodies\images";` which should read as `$srcc = "C:\wamp\www\foodies\images\";`

Comment: I agree, it's probably an issue with the paths. If they're relative paths (no domain or backslash at the beginning) you may need to qualify them better. If they're relative to the root of your domain, you could try just adding a "/" at the beginning.

Comment: If your code is live online somewhere, post a link so we can have a look.

Comment: @JonStirling Yup, here's an example:
C:/wamp/www/foodies/images/noodles.jpg

I've also tried backslash instead of forward

Comment: @Fred-ii-
Actually that $srcc is comment. I dont think it is useful here because I am taking location from DB. I was just trying ;)

Comment: @mopo922 - Sorry, but I didn't get you. where to add that slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late reply to this. This was resolved. The issue was that I was giving location starting from root drive and not from root of web folder where the images were actually stored.
Ex: Website and images were located in C:\WAMP\my_site\images\
Instead of giving location from website root folder "\my_site\images\" I was giving it from C:\WAMP.......

Minor mistake though! ;)

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand what's going on with the `<img>` tag.  The `src` attribute needs to be a URL that tells your Web browser how to access the image, not a local file path.  (URLs can be made for accessing local files, but that doesn't seem to be what you're doing, and that won't help you make Web-ready software anyway.)

Comment: I took that from a previous post for the same issue.
I also tried:
<img src="<?php=$img ?>" width=100 height=100/>

Answer (score 0):

The best way to display images from database is to save the image path in database tables then use [Data URLS Schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).
Try this instead:

```
<?php $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "foodies");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Failed to connect to mysql";
}
$sql = "select img, name from products";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$img = $row["img"];
$name = $row["name"];

echo "<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode( $img); ?>" width=200 height=200/>";
?>
```

The $img is the image file name, without the extension. Let's say you have saved your image in a folder "image" and the image file extension is jpeg.
I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 if($row['file_location']=="")
{
//your code
}
else
{
?>
<a href="uploads/<? echo $row['file_location']?>" target="new">VIEW IMAGE</a>
<?php
}
}
```

Comment: uploads/ is the folder name